# Django Password Reset Email Error 10060

Tags: python, django

I can't get the built in Django Password-reset to work. I'm trying to test it with my Gmail-account but I'm getting an Error 10060 at /resetpassword/.

My urls:

```
url(r'^resetpassword/passwordsent/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done'),
url(r'^resetpassword/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset'),
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
url(r'^reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),
```

My settings:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

I've opened port 25 in the Firewall.

Any ideas? Other settings i might have forgotten? Thank you for your answers!

EDIT:

**EMAIL_PORT = 587 is working!**

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your port is wrong - you will need to use port 465 instead of port 25.

[This help article](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) indicates that you should be using port 465 with SSL.

Comment: Thank you but Im getting the same error with that port. Any other ideas? I've tried to follow the django docs on this.